# Authenticate linux client to an openldap server?

Tags: authentication, ldap, openldap

ok i am fairly new to linux, i am currently switching careers to be a linux admin instead of windows admin. how exactly do you authenticate an ubuntu server to an openLDAP domain? i have went through like 3-4 articles that have all these crazy instructions but none of them worked. I would think its pretty simple but it seems harder than installing and configuring openldap?

Comment: what Ubuntu version do you plan to use, what article you use and what didn't work?

Comment: I am using ubuntu server 14.04 and i tried using the instructions in this article  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication               pretty much i don't understand what needs to be done. so i have my openldap server i installed the ldap-client on the other linux machine. and now i am confused i followed the steps in the article and still can't login with a ldap user account

Comment: To setup the actually OpenLDAP server use this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-a-basic-ldap-server-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps). To connect it to the client use this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-client-computers-using-ldap-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps)

Comment: Will this tutorial work with Ubuntu 14.04? it shows its for 12?

Answer (score 0):

Well i followed the tutorial that tilbunt specified i should use and now my ubuntu server won't even boot up(very discouraged at this point), so i'm going to look for a GUI alternative or something like that